# How can I call a method from a name string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-jira

I am using an API to call specific information from a website. I need to be able to parse through the list to utilize the functions. Example:

```
list = ['doThis','doThat']
for item in list:
    sampleobject.item
```

The issue is when I use this, I get an error saying "sampleobject has no attribute 'item'".

Is there a way that I can pull the quote out of the string to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
methods = ['doThis','doThat']
for method_name in methods:
    method = getattr(sampleobject, method_name)
    method()
```

Though it would be easier to do:

```
sampleobject.doThis()
sampleobject.doThat()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getattr(sampleobject, item)` to get the content of a property with the name equal to what is stored in item, which is an element from your list.
I think the problem is not about quotes at all. The problem is that syntax `object.member` means: evaluate a property named `member` that is stored in a variable named `object`. And you expect it to mean: evaluated a property with the name stored in `member`.